# To get images from device and show images in uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have get images from device by these links [mutiselectimagepicker](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

and 
[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

I have tried both links and works good.
when i click on done button the path looks like this

```
<UIImage: 0x7fca78772510>, {485, 303}
```

but how can i get those selected images to my collection view
and how can i print selected images paths...

Comment: you can't get image path because ios not provides image path or not get image name also.

Comment: ok...but how can i get those selected images to my collectionview @dharmesh Dhorajiya

Comment: i add answer please check it. you use `ELCImagePickerController ` delegate method to get image.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing is the description of a `UIImage` object, it contains the address of the memory where the image resides and the size.
`UIImage`s don't have a path because they are object created in the heap memory, they can be created from a file but they doesn't bring that information.
Once you have your `UIImage` instance you can easily pass to the image property of a `UIImageView`, not path needed.

Comment: ok but when i got images in array and get it in collection view it is not shown in it... and no error...

Comment: Keep image instances in an array is not a good design solution, app memory will grow app fast and the system can kill your app after a certain limit. By the way your problem is elsewhere, are you sure that the image view where are you passing the image exists?

Comment: if that image not exist then how can i see it in imgepicker? and how can i get it address..it existt

Comment: the image view not the image, in the mmethod that return the cell, before the "return cell" statement put a breakpoint and write "po cell.imgggg" in the console when it breaks, let's see if exist, if it is connected, if it has a frame

Comment: I have a new problem..I have take button to open image picker view but collection view methods are called after view did load.. so how can any images will in array without choosing any images. but when i select images then collection methods are not calling again..